# MySQL forcing MySQL to use an index it doesn't think is possible

Tags: mysql

TL;DR; MySQL thinks an index is not possible for the query but due to low cardinality it is still quicker to use it with all values. Is there a way to force MySQL to always use the composite index even though it think's it isn't a possible index?

*Full question...*

I have the state of a queue system stored in MySQL. Queue items are pushed to a queue server, but we use the database to ensure 1 time only processing of dependant objects over processing nodes.

There are multiple queues being tracked in the same table, identified by a `queue_name` varchar field. The state of any item can be one of `queued`, `processing`, `done`, or `failed`. To quickly count or fetch outstanding items there is an composite index on `queue_name` + `status`.

`queue_name` is a very low cardinality column (there are currently only 3 possible values).

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `queue_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('queued','processing','done','failed') NOT NULL,
  `payload` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `queue_queue_name_status_index` (`queue_name`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When fetching all items in the `processing` state MySQL does a full table scan.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM queue WHERE status IN ('queued', 'processing');

  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: queue
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1036882
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

This would be as I expect as there is no "suitable" index to shortcut this select.

However, given that I know the `queue_name` column has very low cardinality, I can achieve the same query listing every possible `queue_name` value as:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM queue 
   WHERE queue_name IN ('default', 'email', 'order') /* All values */
       AND status IN ('queued', 'processing');

  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: queue
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: queue_queue_name_status_index
          key: queue_queue_name_status_index
      key_len: 767
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

This correctly uses the composite index, and filters from 1M rows to 5-10 depending on the current data.

This is much faster for the same result. I have tried telling MySQL to use that index, but the query planner seems to throw it away and ignore. E.g.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM queue 
    FORCE INDEX (queue_queue_name_status_index) 
    WHERE status IN ('queued', 'processing');

  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: queue
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1037684
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

This produces the same explain, and slow query, as not specifying an index. The index is not shown as possible index, and is not used.

Is there a way to force MySQL to always use the composite index even though it think's it isn't a possible index? The query planner always rules it out, so even if you use `FORCE INDEX` MySQL will decide against using the index and do a full table scan instead. This is obviously much slower.

Comment: create index with status column first

Comment: `analyze table` to update cardinalities maybe helps?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Sure, we could just create a separate index on the status column alone, but I'd rather our DB had one less index to maintain if possible. It's quite a high throughput table. Given that MySQL already has to sub-index that field, it just feels like a waste to do it twice.

Comment: @AndySavage delete old one of course, you cannot force mysql to use sub-column without filter on top column, this is how indexes work

Comment: @IlyaBursov I need the other index as the main use case is to query by name + status (as you would expect for a queue). Unfortunately we now have another use-case where it's status alone. I know it's not how indexes work, it's just a funny edge case where using the "wrong" index would still be faster. I'm expecting it to not be possible, but figured it was interesting enough of a question to ask. Maybe there is some trickery I'm not aware of.

Comment: single index (status, name) can be used for both your use cases

Comment: Ah I now see what you mean. Apologies @IlyaBursov, I misunderstood your first comment. Yes, that would work. That's embarrassingly simple! We would lose speed on total counts per queue, but then I guess we can't have everything together anyway.

Comment: @AndySavage you could have another table with total counts per queue, which will be populated by triggers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to force it outside what you have already done; though it might be simpler (and faster) to replace the "forcing" condition `queue_name IN ('default', 'email', 'order')` with something like `queue_name <> 'someimpossiblevalue'`.

`queue_name IS NULL` might be even faster since the field is defined as `NOT NULL`, allowing the MySQL optimizer to replace it with "TRUE"; but it could end up back ignoring the index as well. It's worth a shot.

Comment: Great idea. When using `NOT NULL` it now shows as a possible index in the query planner, yet MySQL still doesn't use it (even with `FORCE INDEX`). Tantalisingly close!

Comment: If you know it can't be a blank string either; `queue_name <> ''` might be the best solution as (I'd guess) it has the least string comparison logic.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid. Lists as a possible index (which `force` alone does not achieve), but still doesn't use it.